# How to use mongo Query to fetch data from nested documet

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

Here is the document.

How to use mongoQuery on **branchId** which have to value is **e63a5343-871c-47ee-8fe6-31d9b7f9fa1b1** and returns data only have this branchId.

I'm using

> db.collection.find({
>        'checkinDetails.presenceTable': { $elemMatch: 
>              {'priorityDevice.branchId':"e63a5343-871c-47ee-8fe6-31d9b7f9fa1b1"}}

```
{
 "checkinDetails": {
       "userCount": NumberInt("9"),
       "presenceTable": [
        {
        "entity": {
            "entityCategory": "Users",
            "entityType": "User",
            "entityName": "Raghvendra",
            "id": "25d156df-2c7e-4506-a5b0-969bf5d0745b"
        },
        "fromState": "current",
        "priorityDevice": {
            "aclFlag": false,
            "zoneGranularity": NumberInt("300000"),
            "csId": "0577936e-f81c-4386-bae7-0255a28ee374",
            "branchId": "e63a5343-871c-47ee-8fe6-31d9b7f9fa1b1",
            "txPower": NumberInt("-54"),
            "filterRSSI": -63.15999016102085,
            "rssi": NumberInt("-55"),
            "time": "2019-01-17T14:38:11.804Z",
            "zoneId": "e813b2f3-88f8-4111-b2bb-50bb7dfb0ba7",
            "deviceId": "26341b09-9b16-4de4-a9ce-74dd3a858be8"
        }
    },
    {
        "entity": {
            "entityCategory": "Users",
            "entityType": "User",
            "entityName": "Rahul Saini",
            "id": "8f067f5b-6a8f-4237-a760-109303def580"
        },
        "fromState": "current",
        "priorityDevice": {
            "aclFlag": false,
            "zoneGranularity": NumberInt("300000"),
            "csId": "0577936e-f81c-4386-bae7-0255a28ee374",
            "branchId": "e63a5343-871c-47ee-8fe6-31d9b7f9fa1b",
            "txPower": NumberInt("-54"),
            "filterRSSI": -66.44148222664761,
            "rssi": NumberInt("-61"),
            "time": "2019-01-17T14:38:11.803Z",
            "zoneId": "e813b2f3-88f8-4111-b2bb-50bb7dfb0ba7",
            "deviceId": "26341b09-9b16-4de4-a9ce-74dd3a858be8"
        }
    },
    {
        "entity": {
            "entityCategory": "Users",
            "entityType": "User",
            "entityName": "Shubham Saurabh",
            "id": "4f0fe333-3f9f-457f-8046-5476573323fb"
        },
        "fromState": "current",
        "priorityDevice": {
            "aclFlag": false,
            "zoneGranularity": NumberInt("300000"),
            "csId": "0577936e-f81c-4386-bae7-0255a28ee374",
            "branchId": "e63a5343-871c-47ee-8fe6-31d9b7f9fa1b1",
            "txPower": NumberInt("-62"),
            "filterRSSI": -61.489655691672645,
            "rssi": NumberInt("-57"),
            "time": "2019-01-17T14:38:11.799Z",
            "zoneId": "e813b2f3-88f8-4111-b2bb-50bb7dfb0ba7",
            "deviceId": "26341b09-9b16-4de4-a9ce-74dd3a858be8"
        }
    }
]
"type": "presenceTable"
  }
```

Comment: You actually looking for mongoose query  or MongoDB query?

Comment: I am looking MongoDB query

Comment: Check my answer now as I edited , hope it will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding to your comment. Try this example to fetch data using MongoDB query.
`db.collection.find({ checkinDetails: { presenceTable: { priorityDevice : { branchId :"e63a5343-871c-47ee-8fe6-31d9b7f9fa1b1"} }  } })`

 More infromation you can find here : https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-embedded-documents/

Comment: "priorityDevice" is inside in "presenceTable" and missing "presenceTable" key in your query.

Comment: Well sorry about that then I will edit my answer to also include `presenceTable`

Comment: Sorry! according to the above "document" `presenceTable` key is inside in `checkinDetails`

Comment: According to your query
`db.collection.find({ presenceTable: { checkinDetails: { priorityDevice : { branchId :"e63a5343-871c-47ee-8fe6-31d9b7f9fa1b1"} }  } })`

Comment: Check my answer now

Comment: I want to fetch only 2 objects `Raghvendra` and `Shubham` which have branchId `e63a5343-871c-47ee-8fe6-31d9b7f9fa1b1 `

Comment: Yes I think above query fetch data only if brancId is equal to what you want

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186876/discussion-between-rahul-saini-and-gabriel-costin).